# iPhone 6s plus keyboard hanging issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have my app's login page where I am unable to type the text in the username field, where as I am able to type in the password field. When i'm trying to enter the text in username field, application is hanging.  It's happening only `iPhone 6S Plus` device. Works fine in other **ios devices** that runs the **same os version.**

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: If Possible plz share screen shot for the same ...